# Request a paper by Gelfand and Ponomarev

Tags: linear-algebra, reference-request

I am looking for the following paper by Gelfand & Ponomarev:

> I. M. Gelfand and V. A. Ponomarev,  Problems of linear algebra and classification of
>   quadruples of subspaces in a finite-dimensional vector space,  Colloquia Mathematica
>   Societatis Ianos Bolyai,  5,  Hilbert space operators,  Tihany (Hungary),  1970,163—237

Many thanks in advance for finding the paper for me!

Comment: Do you know whether it exists in english? Because it could be it is only in russian.

Comment: Well, it seems to be it exists in english, but this is probably a paper of the kind that only mathematics departments in universities can have access to. Try there.

Comment: This is not even on http://www.mathnet.ru/php/person.phtml?option_lang=rus&personid=8938 . Looks like a reference that is being carried along from paper to paper without the authors ever having seen it. Probably interlibrary loans are the most efficient way of getting it.

Comment: Do you know the hungarian title? I found nothing in my uni library database.

Comment: @Studenttea No, Sorry!